# transitions aren't working at all with input:focus css

Tags: html, css

I have copied some CSS lines to get a better input style, but I want to make this input has slow transitions when someone clicks on it ( input: focus ). I tried this code

```
transform: translateY(-4px);
```

but I cannot apply time to make it slower

 And if you notice something not clean or unnecessary please remove it
[here is my entire code](https://pastebin.com/raw/2hFvaxcg).

```css
.button-27 {
  appearance: none;
  background-color: #000000;
  border: 2px solid #1A1A1A;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Roobert, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 550;
  line-height: normal;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 60px;
  min-width: 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 16px 24px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  width: 200px;
  will-change: transform;
}

.button-27:disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.button-27:hover {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0 8px 15px;
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}

.button-27:active {
  box-shadow: none;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

$primary: #11998e;
$secondary: #38ef7d;
$white: #fff;
$gray: #9b9b9b;
.form__group {
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 0 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 50%;
}

.form__field {
  font-family: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #9b9b9b;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 7px 0;
  background: transparent;
  &::placeholder {
    color: transparent;
  }
  &:placeholder-shown~.form__label {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    cursor: text;
    top: 20px;
  }
}

.form__label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #9b9b9b;
}

.form__field:focus {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 10s;
  transition: transform 10s;
  transform: translateY(-5px);
  ;
  ~.form__label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #11998e;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #11998e, #38ef7d);
  border-image-slice: 1;
}


/* reset input */

.form__field {
  &:required,
  &:invalid {
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}

.ww {
  font-family: Roobert, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
  color: gray;
  font-size: 20px
}


/* demo */

body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  background-color: #222222;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <label class="ww" for="password">Login : </label>
  <div class="form__group field">
    <input type="input" class="form__field" placeholder="Password" name="username" id='username' required />
  </div> <br>
  <input type="submit" class="button-27" name="submit" value="Get inside">
</center>
```

Comment: FYI, [the center element is obsolete and deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center).

Comment: Please either add the tag of the CSS pre-processor you are using, or include the CSS it produces in the question.

Comment: The only transition rule I see is for the button. What have you tried on the input?

Comment: What exactly would you like to move up? The word Password? It's a placeholder and goes together with the input. Use a label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by putting the

```
  transform: translateY(-3px);
```

in the input:focus
and the `transition: 3s ease;`
in the input